# なっている when does it mean resultant state, and when does it refer to progression?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> バスに乗っている間に眠くなっている

Take for example the sentence above. My question is about when なっている appears with adjectives/verbs such as 暑い、眠い、寒い、酷い　(i.e. adjectives/verbs unlike 死ぬ) and that also have a time duration included e.g. バスに乗っている間に. When does なっている indicate a resultant state and not progression?

Answer (score 1):

Overall, I don't think there is any way to hard and fast way to tell from grammar. You have to judge from context and common usages.

In the example you gave, it seems a bit vague what  (although the usage of 間 to me indicates a change, not a resultant state), so I did a google search and found this paragraph ([here](http://www.o-daira.jp/childhood.html)):

```
保育所が終わって帰ってくると、いつも亡くなった祖父がバス停まで迎えに来てくれていました。
バスに乗っている間に眠くなっていることが多くて、帰りは祖父に背負ってもらい帰ることもありました
```

Having more context makes this much clearer for me, and now I can tell what is going on. I feel this case expresses that the speaker "got sleepy" while on the bus, and then was in a sleepy "state" when getting off the bus, so I would say it is sort of a mix of the two. I would translate the second sentence above as follows:

```
There were many times when I got sleepy while riding the bus, and there were even times when my grandfather would carry me home.
```

Here is simpler example where context can help distinguish between the two meanings:

```
最近、だんだん暑くなってきてるね。  [pretty clearly 'progressive' meaning, i.e. active change in temperature]
暑くなってる。  [could be either progressive, or state]
暑い           [if you want to talk about simple state, this is the most common way]
```

Comment: なる is a typical instantaneous verb and OP's example will be perceived as a resultant state usage by anyone unless extra information is hidden. You can virtually interpret it as a resultant state unless it has adverbs like "gradually"(as you say), "just now" or so.